# (FFMPEG) Scroll multi images from bottom to top continuously

Tags: ffmpeg, images, scrolling

I have a folder contains 100 images, I want to make a video from these images by scrolling them continuously, please help me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Same resolution?

Comment: @Gyan yes, same res!